# Sync GeoServer data directory with S3

Tags: geoserver

I want to deploy multiple GeoServer instances using AWS Elastic BeanStalk. In order to do this, I figured I have to keep my data dir somewhere else, like S3. I suppose the naive way to do this is to set up a job to run "s3 sync" every 30 seconds or something like that.

Has anyone ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can mount S3 as a file system on your machine (there are Linux filesystems to do that, might be available for other operating systems as well) and then store the data directory there.

The trouble is that GeoServer loads in memory the data dir contents at startup, and won't look back at it unless you issue a reload command (available also [via the REST API](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/reload.html)), which will reload everything (so, can be pretty slow when you have many layers).

Comment: Do you have an idea how that would be performance-wise for big GeoTIFFs, like 5GB?

Comment: As far as I know, the reload time is proportional to the number of stores and layers configured in GeoServer, not to the size of the data contained in them.